# Integrating React with Django in Visual Studio

Tags: django, visual-studio, reactjs

How can I integrate Django with React in Visual Studio? Can anyone help me out with the steps in creating the folders and installing the package?

Comment: How's it going?

Answer (score 0):

If you are set on using the combination of both Django and Reactjs, I recommend that you consider using Django to handle the backend via REST API and using React for the front end.

To get started with this you can try the django rest framework tutorial to help you get comfortable with the django/rest api side of things.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/#tutorial

I personally prefer to keep the backend seperate from the front end.

For development purposes I would simply organise my folders like:

/project-folder/backend (django)
/project-folder/frontend (reactjs)

Good luck!